# How can you use a defined function into certain rows of a DataFrame?

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a problem with a python excercise of dataframes that the teacher gave us, it goes like this:

Calculate the mean of each of the variables 'Avg_User_IMDB' and 'Avg_User_Rtn_Tom' and save those values as mean_1 and mean_2, respectively.

After that, write a function called `qualify()` that receives a line as an argument and grades the movie as follows:

If the actor is 'Sean Connery' or 'Daniel Craig' and Avg_User_IMDB > mean_1 and Avg_User_Rtn_Tom > mean_2, then it should return 'excellent', otherwise return 'regular'.

I have already have written all the code that I could, but it doesn´t prints anything. Here is what I have:

```
mean_1 = dfbond['Avg_User_IMDB'].mean()
mean_2 = dfbond['Avg_User_Rtn_Tom'].mean()
print(mean_1)
print(mean_2)

is_SirSeanConery = dfbond['Bond_Actor'] == 'Sir Sean Connery'
is_DanielCraig = dfbond['Bond_Actor'] == 'Daniel Craig'

tam = int(input('How many rows are you gona use: '))
if tam < 1:
    print('¡DOESN´T HELP!')
else:
    row = []
    for i in range(tam):
        print ('Write the rows', str(i + 1) + ": ",end="")
        ol = int(input())
        row.append(ol)
    print('The rows are: ', row)

def qualify(row):
    r = dfbond.iloc[row]
    final = r[['Bond_Actor','Avg_User_IMDB','Avg_User_Rtn_Tom']]
    for i in final:
        if dfbond['Bond_Actor'] == is_SirSeanConery or is_DanielCraig:
            if  dfbond['Avg_User_IMDB'] > mean_1 and dfbond['Avg_User_Rtn_Tom'] > mean_2:
                print('Excellent')
            else:
                print('Regular')
        else:
            print('Regular')
    
print(final)
```

And it gives me this error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-a16ac904974e> in <module>
     11             print('Regular')
     12 
---> 13 print(final)

NameError: name 'final' is not defined
```

Comment: Iindent the last line by one tab to fix the immediate NameError. However, you never call qualify anywhere so you should probably do that somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Call qualify() function. You can't directly use variables within a function.

```
def qualify(row):
    r = dfbond.iloc[row]
    final = r[['Bond_Actor','Avg_User_IMDB','Avg_User_Rtn_Tom']]
    for i in final:
        if dfbond['Bond_Actor'] == is_SirSeanConery or is_DanielCraig:
            if  dfbond['Avg_User_IMDB'] > mean_1 and dfbond['Avg_User_Rtn_Tom'] > mean_2:
                print('Excellent')
            else:
                print('Regular')
        else:
            print('Regular')
    
qualify(row)
```